# Making a delete confirmation page using Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, action

I am trying to add a new page to my RoR3 application that should display a delete confirmation of a user account. It should match the 'destroy' action in 'ROOT_RAILS/controllers/accounts_controller.rb'.

At this time my problem occurs on creating a "link_to" this page, but maybe I am wrong somewhere and my work is not completed yet.

So, what I made, is:

1. I created the 'ROOT_RAILS/views/accouns/delete.html.erb' file.
2. I updated the routes.rb like this:

   ```
   resources :accounts do
     collection do
       get 'delete'
       post 'delete'
     end
   end
   ```

I don't know the next steps, but now if I try to insert this code

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_account_path(@current_account) %>
```

in my views, I will get this error:

```
undefined method `delete_account_path' for #<#<Class:0x00...>
```

**What I have to do?**

---

This "link_to" works, but, of course, doesn't make what I would like:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_users_accounts_path %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

config/routes.rb:

```
resources :accounts do
  get :delete, :on => :member
end
```

In the view before the delete page:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_account_path(@current_account) %>
```

In the delete view(this will invoke the destroy method in your controller):

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @current_account, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```